# How to within a specific time; plot the highest high and the lowest low in Pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I'm currently stuck in implementing Specific time  while plotting the highest high and the lowest low of candle within a session say 0500 - 0800.
I already was successfully with the 24 hour pivotal previous highest high and previous lowest low.

```
study("Color highest bar", overlay = true)

newSession = change(time('D'))

[lo,hi] = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', [low,high], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

isToday = (year == year(timenow)) and (month == month(timenow)) and (dayofmonth == dayofmonth(timenow))
isHist  = not isToday

lobar   = lo == low
hibar   = hi == high

bgcolor(newSession       ? color.white  : na, transp = 75)
bgcolor(lobar and isHist ? color.red    : na, transp = 75)
bgcolor(hibar and isHist ? color.green  : na, transp = 75)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `input.session` to get the session time and then use the `time()` function to figure out if you are in that session.

Compare current high/low price with the ones you store in memory while you are in the session and update them if necessary.

```
//@version=5
indicator('HHLL', overlay=true)

session_time = input.session("0500-0800", "Session")

is_in_session = time(timeframe.period, session_time)
is_new_session = not is_in_session[1] and is_in_session

var float hh = na
var float ll = na

if (is_new_session)
    hh := high
    ll := low
else if (is_in_session)
    if (high > hh)
        hh := high
    
    if (low < ll)
        ll := low

plot(is_in_session ? hh : na, "HH", color.green, 1, plot.style_circles)
plot(is_in_session ? ll : na, "LL", color.red, 1, plot.style_circles)
```

[image]